# Long aspx file gets hard to read - is there a way to simplify

Tags: asp.net

My aspx file has lot's of components and has become difficult to work with when eg. adding new items because I can't see the start and end tags of where the new control must go (especially when adding containers).

I was wondering if there is a way to arrange the code with some kind of placeholder (all within the same file is fine) - something along the lines of the mockup below?

```
<abc:container>
    <abc:pages>
        <abc:page>
            [Page1CodeGoesHere]
        </abc:page>
        <abc:page>
            [Page2CodeGoesHere]
        </abc:page>
    </abc:pages>
</abc:container>


<Page1CodeGoesHere>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</Page1CodeGoesHere>

<Page2CodeGoesHere>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>b</td>
            <td>c</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</Page2CodeGoesHere>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [ASP.NET User Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wt3k2fyw(v=vs.140).aspx). It allow you to use code from separate files.

Comment: That is one idea but I don't really want the hassle of user controls, nothing is re-usable anyway so I think that would be an overkill.

Comment: ASPX out of the box does not allow to do exactly same that you want. You can use ASCX controls or other way is to it by JavaScript. Make "Page1CodeGoesHere" and "Page2CodeGoesHere" html blocks invisble and on the bottom of page and move them to right place and make visible on page load. But it seems also to be an overkill.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for code-folding a-la `#region` support.

If yes, then Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 added support for `#region`s in HTML editor. You would use it like this:

```
<!-- #region Page1Code -->
..
<!-- #endregion -->
```

This will allow you to collapse-expand the regions as convenient to you.

Ref: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/10/16/announcing-new-web-features-in-visual-studio-2013-update-4-rc.aspx

*Note 1*:

This was voted against for in VS 2015, but was declined. So, `#region` support for HTML editor is here to stay it seems. Ref: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6571662-do-not-introduce-the-curse-of-regions-to-html

*Note 2*:

Nothing beats modular approach. Keep your pages small, clean and simple.

Comment: Regions may help, I can already collapse the tags in the html anyway though. My page is actually quite simple but I use the Telerik controls with Splitter + Tab + Panes + charts and this translates to 4 pages of xaml which is hard to navigate.    Perhaps collapsing the code is the way to go.

Comment: @A_L: In that case regions will help you to group multiple related controls as one group which you can then expand/collapse. See them as containers as you depicted in your question.